# Laravel 7: How to show data comparing to nearest date?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-7

I want to show data in my table comparing to the nearest date. There is a table named `customers` in my database. To view data I used `orderBy` for `schedule` column. But it's not solving my problem. I need to view data which is nearest to the date.
Example:

| id | schedule_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-25 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 2022-07-23 |
| 4 | 2022-07-15 |

Today date is : `2022-07-21`. So, I want to show the data from this table like this:

| id | schedule_date |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-07-15 |
| 3 | 2022-07-23 |
| 1 | 2022-07-25 |
| 2 | null |

It will show data comparing with today date to nearest schedule date. The date which already passed it will show first, the nearest date will show second and the null schedule_date data will show last.

I tried with this code:

```
$customer = Customer::where('isDelete', 0)->orderBy('schedule_date', 'asc')->get();
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: what's the output you are getting now with your current code?

Comment: It's just showing data according to schedule date in ascending order. And schedule date null data shows first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Customer::orderByRaw('ISNULL(schedule_date), schedule_date ASC')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this single code solve my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_case.asp)

```
    $date = '2022-07-21';
    $customer = Customer::where('isDelete', 0)
    ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN `schedule_date` < ? THEN 2 WHEN `schedule_date` => ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC', [$date, $date])->get()
```